# Upgrade and update Ubuntu server

Tags: 12.04, server, upgrade, updates, lts

There is a ubuntu server 12.04 LTS; and I want to be up to date and updated with security updates and have the most up to date version of packages installed.

but **i do not want the server to change from LTS version to other versions**. **IF So only from one LTS version to another LTS version.**
What commands should I regularly use to keep the server up to date ??

Answer (score 1):

1) Update your local package index with your sources,

```
apt-get update
```

2) Upgrade the newest version of all the packages you have installed,

```
apt-get upgrade
```

apt-get upgrade will use the sources that are listed under /etc/apt/sources.list